# How do I Rename a .301 file to add a component to Tina-ti?

Tags: operational-amplifier, spice, pspice, tina, ne5532

I'm trying to import a model of an NE5534 to TINA-ti that I downloaded from the TI site. The file has the .301 extension. I'm not really sure how I can use this, because I need a .CIR, .LIB, .MOD, or .txt file. Can I just modify the file name to a .txt file and upload the new macro that way?

Comment: Is the data inside the file in the correct format? Merely changing a file's extension doesn't convert it to a different format, but sometimes different extensions exist for the same format.

Comment: @Hearth When I rename to a txt file, the data inside is legible and make sense to me, but I'm unfamiliar with the syntax differences between a cir, lib, mod, and txt file, so I'm worried that Tina-ti won't understand it because I can't name it with the right extension. I downloaded the file from Texas Instruments site for the ne5534. Does that help?

Comment: Does it look like SPICE? if it doesn't use any A-devices it will probably work on any SPICE simulator, though you may have to change some syntax (parentheses vs curly braces kind of stuff). (You might also encounter problems if it uses Z-devices, which are less commonly supported but almost never used.)

Comment: @Hearth Sorry I'm new to this spice stuff. It ended up being a sub circuit file, just with a .301 extension for some reason. I changed the extension to .lib and was able to use the new macro command in Tina to import it. Simulates well now. Thank you for the help!